# Java compare array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm really stuck over here. I'm just wondering if there's another way to compare the array to key of HashMap? Please see my comments on my code

```
          ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList();
                datalist.add("test,test2,test3,test4");
                datalist.add("test2,test,test3,test4");
                datalist.add("test3,test4,test,test2");

         Map<String,String> hashdata = new HashMap();
                        hashdata= setHashMap(datalist);
     Set data_key = hashdata.keySet(); // so i get now the all Key of Hashmap

                String line;
                String[] data;
                LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");

                while(it.hasNext()){
                    line = it.nextLine();

                    data = StringUtils.split(line,(","));

                    //I have this code compare line splitted by ',' compare to key 
                    if(!(data_key.contains(data[0]))){
System.out.println("Invalid");


                    //But what I want is to compare KeySet to line splitted by ','
                    if(//statement here){

                    }

                }

            private static Map<String,String> setHashMap(ArrayList<String> inputlist){
                   String[] data;
                   Map<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                   for(int i=0; i<inputlist.size(); i++){
                       data = inputlist.get(i).split(",");
                       hashmap.put(data[0], data[1]);
                   }
                   return hashmap;
                }
```

Data on file :

```
test1,test2,test3
test2,test3,test1
test3,test2,test1
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: what do you mean "compare the elements of arraylist to line". Do you mean to see if any item in datalist matches any of the tokens in the input line, not just data[0]? If you want to see if any of the items in datalist are found in each line read in, then for each line read,

Comment: oops...continuing...check `line.contains(<current item in iteration of list>)`

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: That's what your code is doing now.

Comment: I edited again my question sorry about that. I want to compare the first index on line to arraylist. My code is comparing if the index is equals to Arraylist. But what I want to do is to compare my ArrayList on index.

Comment: You keep saying more or less the same thing, and I keep not getting it.  Are you trying to say that you want to test whether *all* corresponding elements of the array list are equal?

Comment: I think he's saying that he wants to do what his code is already doing. But he doesn't realize that his code already works.

Comment: No, I want to do the opposite comparing. "I want to compare the elements of ArrayList on Indexes of line". For example, the element of ArrayList is "test1" and the index[0] of line is "test2".

Comment: It would be really, really helpful if you provided not only example input, but the corresponding desired *results*.

Comment: You say the element of ArrayList is "test1", but your data on file does not contain such an entry. Maybe you mean to split each entry in the array list? e.g. the first entry contains "test1,test2,test3" and your first token from the input line is "test2". You want to see if splitting the array list entry yields a match? Then iterate the array list. For each entry split the entry into an array of tokens using comma as separator. Then that will give you a String array. Use Arrays.asList to convert to a temporary list, then see if that temporary list "contains" the token you get from input line.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming You need to describe exactly what conditions qualify a line as matching your ArrayList without using the word "compare."  Do you want to check whether `data` has any Strings *in common* with the ArrayList?  Do you want to check whether `data` contains *exactly the same strings* as the ArrayList, regardless of order?

Answer (score 1):

I would join your list using [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String)) to create one single string, and the compare it to each line, rather thansplitting the file into an array and iterate both the array against the list.

You can use a java code like this:

```
ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
datalist.add("test");
datalist.add("test2");
datalist.add("test3");

String line;
String data = StringUtils.join(datalist, ',');

LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");

while (it.hasNext()) {
    line = it.nextLine();

    if (data.equals(line)) {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method will allow you to pick a specific index from an ArrayList. ([See Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

Here are a few ways to compare your defined ArrayList with an input array.  If one of theses satisfies your needs, please let us know which one. ;)

```
public class temp {
    ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList();
    datalist.add("test");
    datalist.add("test2");
    datalist.add("test3");

    String line;
    String[] data;
    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");

    while(it.hasNext()){
        line = it.nextLine();

        data = StringUtils.split(line,(","));

        //I have this code compare line to elements of arraylist
        if(datalist.contains(data[0]){
            System.out.println("Valid A");
        }

        // Test specific element of array list against a specific index in the file
        if(data[0] == datalist.get(0)){
            System.out.println("Valid B");
        }

        //test specific element in array list against each element in line
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            if(data[i] == datalist.get(0)){
                System.out.println("Valid C for index " + i);
            }

        //test if array list contains any element in line
        for (String element : datalist) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                if (datalist.contains(data[0])){
                    System.out.println("Valid D for index " + i);
                }
        }

    }

}
```